# getting Module not found: ValidationError while importing svg file in webpack react setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, webpack-5

I have a manual Webpack 5, react setup with typescript and I am trying to import an SVG icon. Also I am using material UI in the project. The problem is that I am getting an error while trying to use it after importing it. Error is

```
Module not found: ValidationError: Invalid generator object. Asset Modules Plugin has been initialized using a generator object that does not match the API schema.
generator has an unknown property 'filename'. These properties are valid:
   object { dataUrl? }
Generator options for asset/inline modules.
```

This is how my webpack.common.js file looks

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "src", "index.tsx"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "./src/assets/index.html"),
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },

            // --------- Webpack 5 rule for images ---------
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "assets/images/[name][ext][query]",
                },
            },
            // --------- Webpack 5 rule for svg's and fonts ---------
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
                type: "asset/inline",
                generator: {
                    filename: "assets/fonts/[name][ext][query]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Want to use this SVG icon in deleteIcon prop on material ui chip component. However this is giving error. Also tried importing the icon as png than putting it in src prop of img tag provided to material ui deleteIcon prop but then alt prop is shown instead of icon provided in img src.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the error is about the configuration setup for the type: "asset/inline" in webpack config. According to error message, "filename" property is not a valid property to use for type: "asset/inline". Instead of "filename", try using "dataUrl". You can follow the below example:
[https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-data-uri-generator][1]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure how to configure it.

Comment: @ShogunKoDogun
You can follow the link below:
[https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-data-uri-generator](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-data-uri-generator)

Comment: @ShogunKoDogun, You can configure custom uri generator for svgs as mentioned below:  `const miniSVGDataURI = require('mini-svg-data-uri');` ` // ...`  `{ test: /\.svg$/, type: 'asset/inline', generator: { dataUrl(content) { content = content.toString(); return miniSVGDataURI(content); } }, use: 'svgo-loader' },` ] It transforms a svg as the data-url but without base64. It reduces a bundle size a little bit.